# How do I run a Service Fabric exe locally

Tags: c#, console-application, azure-service-fabric

How do I go about running a service built on top of the service fabric runtime just run locally by executing the `*.exe` file?

Currently it just throw an exception then the application is terminated.

I want to be able to spin up the service in isolating so I can test the service end to end before creating the service package before deploying it as part of an application. I've done this previously with TopShelf and Web Jobs but this doesnt seem to work with Service Fabric even though it's just built on top of a console application.

Comment: Most likely you can't *run* it like you can't just run an *asp.net* website.  It has to be hosted, and I'm not aware of a localized Fabric Service host.

Comment: Well all the new stuff like .netcore asp.net can run just locally on its own you don't need anything to support it.

Comment: Actually it can't, you still have to *host* it in something... like an EXE or something.  You can't just *build an exe that runs MVC natively* [you have to configure the exe to host Mvc, and configure MVC with a root directory](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Jun/29/First-Steps-Exploring-NET-Core-and-ASPNET-Core) etc etc, which is still hosting.. it's just not in IIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a local **service fabric cluster** to debug `Service Fabric` applications, but first you need to install the `The Azure Service Fabric SDK`, check this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started) to help you do that.

And then deploy your application in your local cluster, this Microsoft's [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-get-started-with-a-local-cluster) might be useful doing that.

Comment: Is there no way to do this without deploying it to a cluster to run? I normally just spin up the exe's within my test setups then test the application end-to-end then tear it down again. Seems a bit overkill to deploy the whole application each time?

Comment: This is the only way we got to run service fabric apps locally, I think having a local SF cluster is a must.

Comment: @KevinSmith It seems the only way because all of Microsoft's docs are referring to use it; see this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-debugging-your-application) for example

Comment: bit annoying as in the docs it says its a simple console app... but really it's pretty coupled to having to be deployed. In theory it's possible to deploy the application before the test run tests and remove it.

Comment: Yes I agree, but I think even simple console apps that are built using the SF template will have many dependencies on SF itself (for example the settings config), and that is why a local cluster is needed!

Comment: @KevinSmith Kindly mark it as the correct answer if you see this useful for future references.

Comment: Couldn't find a way round this so ended up deploying the application to a local cluster on test setup then tearing it down, actually works pretty well as its fast and you can just deploy the application with a name of `fabric:/{Guid.NewGuid()}`

Answer (score 2):

You can add a regular console app to your solution, reference the service project(s). Then you can create an instance of your service, using mocks for the service context and state manager.

[Here's](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceFabric.Mocks/) an package that will help with the mocks.

[Here's](https://github.com/loekd/ServiceFabric.Mocks/blob/master/README.md) how to use it.

Its use is not limited to unit test scenario's. Make sure you do dependency injection for service remoting (use `IServiceProxyFactory` / `IActorProxyFactory`) instead of using `ServiceProxy.Create`.

If you use `FabricClient`, you'll have to do dependency injection for that too.

Comment: don't really want to mock out any of the code, want to run a end-to-end test per service as it would be within live.

Answer (score 1):

When I want to run things locally as a standalone kestrel, I replace `Program.cs` with the following generic host (for dotnet core 3.1+)

```
public static class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Host
            .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>())
            .Build()
            .Run();
    }
}
```

This may be enough if you are using certain practices such as configuring the service fabric application to read appsettings, etc. as I am doing. The `Startup.cs` is the same, so the IoCC registrations and hosted services are the same.

The only thing a bit special that I have to ensure that my service fabric service is as standard as possible is the following:

In the main service (e.g: the stateless service)

```
protected override IEnumerable<ServiceInstanceListener> CreateServiceInstanceListeners()
{
    return new ServiceInstanceListener[]
    {
        new ServiceInstanceListener(serviceContext =>
            new KestrelCommunicationListener(serviceContext, "ServiceEndpoint", (url, listener) =>
            {
                ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceMessage(serviceContext, $"Starting Kestrel on {url}");

                return new WebHostBuilder()
                            .UseKestrel()
                            .UseCommonConfiguration() //this is custom
                            .ConfigureServices(
                                services => services
                                    .AddSingleton<StatelessServiceContext>(serviceContext))
                            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                            .UseStartup<Startup>()
                            .UseServiceFabricIntegration(listener, ServiceFabricIntegrationOptions.None)
                            .UseUrls(url)
                            .Build();
            }))
    };
}
```

notice the `UseCommonConfiguration()` extension which is:

```
public static class WebHostBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IWebHostBuilder UseCommonConfiguration(this IWebHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
        {
            var env = hostingContext.HostingEnvironment;

            config
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                var appAssembly = Assembly.Load(new AssemblyName(env.ApplicationName));
                config.AddUserSecrets(appAssembly, optional: true);
            }
        });

        return builder;
    }
}
```

I'd like to find a clean way to swap the `Program.cs` depending on whether I run the web application as startup or whether I run the Service Fabric application that contains the services as startup.

Answer (score -1):

To avoid setting up service fabric hassle and debug your web application on your local machine directly you can follow this article in my blog -> [Quest Solution](https://csharpquestsolution.blogspot.com/2021/05/how-to-run-aspnet-core-mvc-solution.html)

You will be able debug your ASP.net application without the need to install Service fabric cluster locally.